# Trouble pulling in Backbone router with Browserify

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, browserify

I’m trying to learn Backbone with Browserify and am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to pull in router.navigate.  But I think it has less to do with Backbone routes and more to do with my lack of knowledge on how to work with modules in Browserify (or just constructors!).

I have a simple “shoutbox” form.  On submit, the fields get saved to the model on the server, which is working.  The problem is when I try to redirect to a different page.

I’m using this line…

```
router.navigate('/shouts', {trigger: true});
```

And I get this error…

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

I’ve tried two different ways with the router.

**EXAMPLE 1**

*main.js*

```
var Router = require('./router');
var router = new Router();
```

*router.js*

```
module.exports = Backbone.Router.extend({
```

*shouts.js*

```
var router = require('../router');
...
router.navigate('/shouts', {trigger: true});
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

*main.js*

```
var router = require('./router');
// var router = new Router();
```

*router.js*

```
module.exports = new Backbone.Router.extend({
```

*shouts.js*

```
var router = require('../router');
...
router.navigate('/shouts', {trigger: true});
```

**1** First I tried exporting just the router constructor.  And then in main.js, I created a ‘new’ router.  And this was working just fine, since all of my routing at that point was simple.  But then I needed a redirect in ShoutEditView.  And I guess it needs access to that router instance?  I tried requiring router.js at the top of the ShoutEditView file and creating a new instance of the router, but that didn’t seem right.  I should be using the same instance I already created I figure.  And anyway, I still got the same error anyway.

**2** So then I tried exporting the router in router.js with ‘new’ in front of it.  So then I could just require it without creating a new instance.  But that doesn’t seem to work either.

I’m thinking, I need to create an instance of the router somewhere and then pass it to the ShoutEditView somehow?

**router.js**

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;

var homeController = require('./controllers/home');
var shoutsController = require('./controllers/shouts');

module.exports = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    'home': homeController.home,
    'shouts': shoutsController.index,
    'shouts/new': shoutsController.new,
    'shouts/:id': shoutsController.show,
    'shouts/:id/edit': shoutsController.edit,
  }

});
```

**main.js**

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;

var router = require('./router');
//var router = new Router();

$('body').on('click', '.back-button', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.history.back();
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

**shoutEditView**

```
var ShoutEditView = new Backbone.View.extend({
  el: '#app',
  events: {'submit': 'save'},
  initialize: function () {
      this.render();
  },
  render: function () {
    var template = require('../templates/shouts/new.html');
    this.$el.html(template());
  },
  save: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var data = $('#foo').serializeObject();
    var shout = new Shout();
    shout.save(data, {
        success: function (shout) {
            console.log(shout.toJSON());
            console.dir(router);
            router.navigate('/shouts', {trigger: true});
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Singleton` pattern should help

```
'use strict';

var $ = require('jquery');
var Backbone = require('backbone');
Backbone.$ = $;

var homeController = require('./controllers/home');
var shoutsController = require('./controllers/shouts');

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

  routes: {
    'home': homeController.home,
    'shouts': shoutsController.index,
    'shouts/new': shoutsController.new,
    'shouts/:id': shoutsController.show,
    'shouts/:id/edit': shoutsController.edit,
  }

});


var _instance;

var SingletonRouter = function() {
    if (_instance === undefined) {
        _instance = new Router();
    }
    return _instance;
};

module.exports = new SingletonRouter();
```

Then

```
var router = require('router');
...
router.navigate('/shouts', {trigger: true});
```